# Can You Save a Clone?

Tags: html, jquery

I am new to web designing, i am currently working on my college project which is based on E-Library system. I am making an admin panel from which you can add new subjects streams and pdfs to the particular subjects. So i wanted to clone a `<div>` which is basically the container of a particular subject like **Commerce** , On the internet today i found this jquery method,

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("button").click(function(){
        $("#empty").clone().appendTo(".container");
      });
    });
    </script>
```

It works fine and this is exactly what i wanted but as you all know whenever the page will refresh it will go to its original format and the cloned element will be deleted or vanished.
So i want to know is there any other way i can add these elemets and they will get saved into the html file and will not get deleted.

(Sorry for my Bad English and Dumb Question)

Comment: Do not clone anything with an ID, change the div ID to class. Yes you can `JSON.stringify()` a DOM object then store it in `localStorage` but that seems cumbersome. Also, your English is fine.

Comment: you can't do this with just html and jquery,  you are trying change the original html file from client side(browser), it will have to involve a bit of backend in order to do that. you are trying to fetch some data form the front and preserve it. you either need a DB of some sort, or you need a mechanism to update your  html file on the server(where ever the file is being served from to the browser).

Comment: Any idea where can i find references of what you guys mentioned in your comment???

Comment: I think other developers could help you more, if you add related ```html``` part of your code to the question.